# How to convert chrome.scripting.executeScript to manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I have a chrome extension in manifest v2 that I need to upgrade to v3.

It's an extension that raises an alarm at a set interval in whichever tab is currently open.

I had the following code in v2 -

background.js

```
  var config = {
    message: displaymessage,
    button: "OK",
    icon: "success",
  };
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    null,
    {
      code: "var config = " + JSON.stringify(config),
    },
    function () {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript(null, { file: "raisealert.js" }, () => {
        console.log("Alarm triggered");
      });
    }
  );
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    null,
    {
      code: "var config = " + JSON.stringify(config),
    },

  );
```

The config was then sent to the file raisealert.js which showed an alert to the user.

I am struggling with converting this to manifest v3. I am getting various errors. The latest one is

```
or in event handler: TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at showpopup()
```

with the code -

background_service_worker.js

```
 let [tab] = chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: () => {
      var config = JSON.parse("${JSON.stringify(config)}");
      return config;
    },
  });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ["raisealert.js"],
  });
  console.log("Alarm triggered");
```

How can I fix this? Essentially, all I want to do is to be able to execute the script - raisealert.js with the config json.

Comment: Use `args` parameter: `func: c => { window.config = c }, args: [config]`